# Invoking a Main() in another .exe and spawning an attached Console window

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application, sandbox, invoke

I'm not sure how to phrase this question so please bear with me.

I am creating a sandbox to run .exes with different privileges. Basically I'm building on the example in this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046(v=vs.110).aspx

Prior to the re-design I'm about to mention, my project had a console application output type (Project->Properties->Application->Output type) despite the fact it was mainly a WPF project. This resulted in both a console window and my GUI being displayed on commencement of the program.

When running a console application IN the sandbox, the output would be written to the already open console window and not create another tied to the .exe under test. I'm trying to avoid this and would prefer my output type to remain as a windows application to prevent a needless console window being open.

As far as I can tell, the issue stems from this line of code:

`target.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, parameters);`

This runs the `Main(string[] args)` method in my .exe under test, however it doesn't spawn its own console window and errors follow swiftly. Is there some way to create a console window and attach the spawned process to it?

Thanks, edits and questions welcome

P.S. With the output type being set to console application, other output types (e.g. forms and wpf projects) load their respective GUIs perfectly fine.

Comment: A process can have only one console window.  You'll have to accommodate for that in your design.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem involves using pInvoke in order to use some of the kernal32 api. Adding these DLLImports:

`[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern int AllocConsole();
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern int FreeConsole();`

These allow me to allocate a console to a process I'm about to launch and I can leave my project as a windows application. All that needs to happen is to enclose my invoke in between Alloc and Free.

As such:

```
 AllocConsole();

 var trythis = target.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, parameters);

 FreeConsole();
```